# Posting a request based on webservice in Android

Tags: android, json, web-services

I am beginer to work with WebServices

```
 Method Type: POST

 Request Parameters :  {loginid:'xxxx@gmail.com', password:'yyyyy'}
```

I was tried like below:

```
  JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
  try {
    jObj.put("loginid", email.getText());
    jObj.put("password", password.getText());
}
```

how can i write the JSON code for it.

Comment: what is issue in this code?

Answer (score 2):

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
try {
    jObj.put("loginid", email.getText());
    jObj.put("password", password.getText());
}

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("www.yoursite.com/page");
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jObj.toString());  
se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
post.setEntity(se);
client.execute(post);
```